# How to fix dictionary .values method for list comprehension error in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

The objective is to collect the names of people with positive bank balances and print them out using Python.

```
bank_accounts = {
    'Tom': [0, 1, 5, 3],
    'Jerry': [0, -1, -7, 3],
    'Harry': [0, 1, 2, 3],
}
```

This is the suggested solution but I am trying to condense it into a single line using list comprehension.

```
result = []
for i in bank_accounts.items():
    name = i[0]
    balance = sum(i[1])
    if balance > 0:
        result.append(name)
print(result)
```

Single line code I'm hoping to implement.

```
names = [i for i in bank_accounts if sum(bank_accounts.values()) >0]
print(names)
```

How ever this resulted in a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

I am not sure what went wrong, could anyone please advise?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you what you want:

```
result = [n for n, v in bank_accounts.items() if sum(v) > 0]
```

This produces the following for `result`:

```
['Tom', 'Harry']
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = [i for i in bank_accounts if sum(bank_accounts[i]) > 0]
print(names)
```

you can simply sum on the list off the dict...

```
>>> bank_accounts.get('Tom')
[0, 1, 5, 3]
>>> sum(bank_accounts.get('Tom', []))
9
```

Comment: Why are you using `get`? You can just index the dict. `get` is for when you want some default value if the key isn't present.

Comment: Also, since the original code prints the list directly, changing it to use `', '.join` or `'\n'.join` seems inappropriate.

Comment: force of habit ;P yea you coudl just `bank_accounts[i]`